# How to implement fast import with jgit?

Tags: git, jgit, git-fast-import

is JGIT API providing support for git fast-import?

As of now, we are using git fast-import cli command,but as per our requirement we should not use cli commands.

How to implement fast-import functionality by using pure JGIT API Classes?

Please provide sample or steps to implement git fast-import?

is there any other java API for git fast-import?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know jgit 3.4 currently does not support fast import (as in - write all new objects directly to a pack file).

So your only option would be to slow import and GC afterwards (which will be painfully slow on > 50.000 object repositories)